# Удаление дубликатов Delphi XE

Tags: delphi

**Суть задачи:** Оптимизировать код, что бы: можно было **удалять дубликаты строк** в файлах - **от 300 мегабайт до 2 гигабайт**.

**Цель, которую хотела бы достигнуть:**

Быстрое **удаление дубликатов строк** в текстовом файле.

Ориентировочная скорость обработки файл в 300 мегабайт - 20 - 30 секунд.

Обработка файлов от 300 мегабайт до 2 гигабайт.

**Мой, медленный вариант:**

```
   var
  f1:TextFile;
  st:string;
  s:TStringList;

begin
  AssignFile(F1,'1.txt');
  reset(f1);
  s:=TStringList.Create;
    While not EOF(f1) do
      begin
        readln(F1,st);
        If s.IndexOf(st)<0 then s.Add(st);
      end;

  s.SaveToFile('2.txt');
  s.Free;
  CloseFile(f1);
end;
```

Comment: Можно попробовать https://bitbucket.org/kami-soft/utils/src/bdd3196f7d29dec4ef9ae57c362b332829981265/uBigFileOperations.pas?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default , функция DoRemoveDuplicates.

Comment: @kami, А как её подключить к кнопке? Заранее благодарна.

Comment: я думаю, надо посмотреть, какие параметры принимает функция (они достаточно говорящие)... и вызвать ее с нужными данными в OnClick кнопки. Единственное что... LineFeedStr скорее всего нужно выставить в #13#10, а DefaultEncoding = в TEncoding.UTF8 (наверное)

Comment: @kami, Я начинающая в этом деле, сможете помочь ?

Comment: @kami, если бы смогла бы то не спрашивала :(. к сожалению не получается...

Comment: Важно ли сохранение в выходном файле порядка появления строк во входном файле? Т.е. можно ли строки перемешать?

Comment: @kot-da-vinci, Да, строки можно перемешать. Главное что бы быстро работал код при размерах, текстовых файлов - указанных выше.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для быстрого сравнения строк можно воспользоваться функционалом словаря (`TDictionary`), используя строки в качестве ключей. Чтобы сравнение ключей происходило без учета регистра передадим словарю реализацию сравнения ключей без учета регистра (`TOrdinalIStringComparer`). Если строки нужно сравнивать с учетом регистра, то в конструктор словаря ничего не передаем, и тогда будет использована реализация сравнения по умолчанию (с учетом регистра). Поскольку значения для ключей в словаре нам не нужны, то в качестве типа для значения выберем, например, `Integer`. Таким образом, тип для нашего словаря получается таким: `TDictionary<string, Integer>`.

```
uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Generics.Collections,
  System.Generics.Defaults,
  System.Classes;

var
  s: string;
  InputFile: TStreamReader;
  OutputFile: TStreamWriter;
  StrComparer: TOrdinalIStringComparer;
  StrDictionary: TDictionary<string, Integer>;

begin
  InputFile := TStreamReader.Create('1.txt', TEncoding.Default);
  try
    OutputFile := TStreamWriter.Create('2.txt', False, TEncoding.Default);
    try
      OutputFile.BaseStream.Size := 0; // Rewrite(f2);

      // сравниватель строк без учета регистра
      StrComparer := TOrdinalIStringComparer.Create; 
      try
        StrDictionary := TDictionary<string, Integer>.Create(StrComparer);
        try
          while not InputFile.EndOfStream do
          begin
            s := InputFile.ReadLine;

            if not StrDictionary.ContainsKey(s) then
            begin
              // Поскольку нужен только ключ, значение может быть любым
              StrDictionary.Add(s, 0);

              // если перемешивать не нужно, запишем значение сразу
              OutputFile.WriteLine(s);
            end;
          end;

        // если нужно перемешать, запишем значения после того, как все просмотрели
        //  for s in StrDictionary.Keys do
        //    OutputFile.WriteLine(s);
        finally
          StrDictionary.Free;
        end;
      finally
        StrComparer.Free;
      end;
    finally
      OutputFile.Free;
    end;
  finally
    InputFile.Free;
  end;
end;
```

---

**UPD**

Файл размером 330 МБ (7,3 миллиона строк), при записи результата после обработки (вариант с перемешиванием), обработался за, примерно, 37 секунд. При записи результата во время обработки (без перемешивания) - за, примерно, 36 секунд. Итоговый файл получился размером 280 МБ (6,7 миллиона строк).

Можно попробовать ускорить процесс распараллелив его на разные потоки, но это вряд ли даст прирост в разы, поскольку много времени уйдет на согласование работы этих потоков. И еще одно "узкое место" - это операции чтения/записи на диск.

**UPD2**

Попробовал читать файл с HDD и писать результат на SSD. Получилось на 1 секунду быстрее.

Comment: Читаю и пишу на один и тот же SSD.

Comment: @Татьяна, рад помочь :)

Answer (score 4):

Можно попробовать нативные средства TStringList борьбы с дубликатами.
К сожалению, они работают только для сортированных списков:

```
var
  f1:TextFile;
  st:string;
  s:TStringList;

begin
  AssignFile(F1,'1.txt');
  reset(f1);
  s:=TStringList.Create;
  s.Sorted:=True;
  s.Duplicates:=dupIgnore;
    While not EOF(f1) do
      begin
        readln(F1,st);
        s.Add(st);
      end;

  s.SaveToFile('2.txt');
  s.Free;
  CloseFile(f1);
end;
```

Если порядок требуется сохранить, придётся самостоятельно реализовывать этот механизм...

```
var
  f1:TextFile;
  st:string;
  s:TStringList;
  dict:TDictionary<string, boolean>;

begin
  AssignFile(F1,'1.txt');
  reset(f1);
  s:=TStringList.Create;
  dict:=TDictionary<string, boolean>.Create
    While not EOF(f1) do
      begin
        readln(F1,st);
        if not map.ContainsKey(st) then
        begin
          dict.Add(st, true);
          s.Add(st);
        end;
      end;

  dict.Free;

  s.SaveToFile('2.txt');
  s.Free;

  CloseFile(f1);
end;
```

Comment: К сожалению при использовании такого подхода - большие файлы не тянет. Но все же за помощь спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Сделала вот так, правда работает очень медленно. Может, у кого? еще есть идеи - как сделать побыстрее ?

```
var
  f1:TextFile;
  st:string;
  s:TStringList;

begin
  AssignFile(F1,'1.txt');
  reset(f1);
  s:=TStringList.Create;
    While not EOF(f1) do
      begin
        readln(F1,st);
        If s.IndexOf(st)<0 then s.Add(st);
      end;

  s.SaveToFile('2.txt');
  s.Free;
  CloseFile(f1);
end;
```